# How to access a package's model?

Tags: laravel

I have a package that implements tagging functionality. In order to create new tags, I need to access the model inside the vendor folder. However, I get an error when I try the following:

```
$tag = new vendor\codecourse\taggy\src\models\tag;
```

> Class 'vendor\codecourse\taggy\src\models\tag' not found

How do I access this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vendor` is assumed. Look at the `namespace` declaration in the file you want to use to figure out the rest. Per https://github.com/codecourse/taggy/blob/master/src/Models/Tag.php, it'll be:

```
$tag = new Codecourse\Taggy\Models\Tag;
```

Comment: you are right, it worked. But how logical is that you don't use vendor and src in the reference? Okay, you could argue that it saves time/shortcut but at least they should have allowed that both references work!

Comment: Allowing both references to work would require more calls to the filesystem to load each class, of which there may be thousands, and there's no reason `src` should be part of the class names.